# Why the Auto-scheduled Finish date is Wrong in this case , using MS Project 2013 ?

Tags: ms-project, scheduling, ms-project-2013

When I set a Auto scheduled task to *Start* date : **07/05/2015** , and *Duration* to **12 month**. I get a *Finish* date of **07/06/2016**.

There is a problem ! The finish day is supposed to be : **07/05/2015**.

I checked the **MyUserCalendar** , it is set to **All days are working days** even weekends. And in `File > Options > Schedule > Days per month` set to **30**.

I don't know where is the problem ? any idea ?

<sub>PS: I am using Microsoft Project 2013.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually if you explicitly set days per month to 30, then by adding 12 months you would have "June 29, 2016" as the finish date.

By adding 365 days to that task you will get "July 4, 2016" and not "July 5, 2016" as you expect since 2016 is a **leap year**.

The deviation to your date might be the amount of hours per day or even the time the activity starts.

Comment: found it , the problem was from **the amount of hours per day** , thank you

Comment: glad I could help :-)